# Android Get some data from XML to Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

After much research,  I can't manage to layout some XML data in my android app.

There is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textview1;  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  GetXmlTask task = new GetXmlTask(textview1 , "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml"); // get the XML
  Log.i("TAG", "test1");
  task.execute(); // execute the task
  Log.i("TAG","test2");
  textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
  Log.i("TAG", "test4");
 }
}
```

And there is my GetXmlTask.java :

```
public class GetXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    public WeakReference<TextView> textViewReference;
    public String url;


    public GetXmlTask(TextView textview, String url) {
        this.textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textview);
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String THEXML = null;

     public String doInBackground(Void... sUrl) {
     try
        {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://3pi.tf/test.xml"); 
        Log.i("TAG2",""+request);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        Log.i("TAG2",""+response);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        Log.i("TAG2",""+resEntity);
        THEXML = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        Log.i("DONNEES XML",""+THEXML);
        }
            catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); } 

     return THEXML;

     }



public Document getDomElement(String task) {

     Log.i("TAG2","test01");
     Document doc = null;
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     try{

     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

     InputSource is = new InputSource();
     is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(task));
     doc = db.parse(is);


     } 

     catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { 
     Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
     return null;
     } 
     catch (SAXException e) {
     Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
     return null;
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
     return null;
     }

     return doc;
     }


     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ){
     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
     }

     //Retrieve each element child element value by using node name of element.
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
         NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
         return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
     }

}
```

As you can see, I put some logcat in to see how it passes through.
I can see all my XML in the logcat with the variable "THEXML" but I can't layout to my mobile app... I did all the method in an AsyncTask because that was highly recommended.. 
Please help me

Thank you

Comment: where is your onPostExecute() method in your Asynctask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a interface as a callback to the activity

```
 GetXmlTask task = new GetXmlTask(ActivityName.this, "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml");
```

Then in GetXmlTask

```
 ReturnData mCallback; 
 public GetXmlTask(Context context, String url) { // Constructor in asynctask
    this.url = url;
    mCallback = (ReturnData)context;
}
```

Then

```
public interface ReturnData
{
      public void Returnxml(String xml);
}
```

In doInbackground you return `THEXML`

```
return THEXML;
```

In `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result)
{
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     if(mCallback!=null)
     {
      mCallback.Returnxml(result);
     } 
}
```

In `MainActivity` implement the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ReturnData {
```

Then

```
public void Retunxml(String data)
{
    textView1.setText(data); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so i add some of your code and i get an error on this line :
GetXmlTask task = new GetXmlTask(MainActivity.this , "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml");

it's MainActivity.this i'm pretty sure because my method wait for a type String

Comment: the constructor GetXmlTask(MainActivity, String) is undefined

Comment: @Nemka no its activity context that is not the problem Do you have a construcotor in asynctask that matches those param. see you do not have a constructor in asynctask. pls follow the whole post

Comment: So I have to create a constructor to the method ?
Sorry I'm a beginner in android ^^

Comment: @Nemka its not a method its constructor of the class. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html. Construcotr will have the same name of the class.can have access modifiers. can have params. no return type

Comment: ok ok you lighting me a little ! Thank you !
but now I don't need this anymore right ? 
"this.textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(mainActivity);"

Comment: @Nemka nope not required. Just make sure you follow the post and it will work. You will see the xml data in textview

Comment: Thank you it works !! I just have to add a scroll to the view to see the whole page, parsing what I want to get ! You are wonderful !
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nemka your next job is to parse the xml using XMl pull parser and get the required data. Check the docs for that. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: ARGH !! That's weird ! when I Change "http://3pi.tf/test.xml" to another xml like "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml" and re-run the app it displays 3pi.tf/test.xml again !! :S any idea ? xD

Comment: @Nemka un- install the app and re-run again. Not the problem with code. New apk is not installed.

Comment: did it already.. :/ 
weird.. it keep in memory the last xml which was working.. even after a uninstall...
I'm looking for another xml

Comment: @Nemka this is not a problem with the code. I am pretty sure of it. However i do not anything else that can solve your current problem.  try posting a new question.

Comment: I tried with "http://www.androidituts.com/source/tutorials.xml" which is a valid xml and it's the same problem ! I'm going to be  stick with one XML for all my life haha. 
yes okay I'll figured out. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the `onPostExecute` method of AsynckTask and handle there the operation over your downloaded file if it is different from null. In you case something like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         if(THEXML !=null)
         {
           //do something
         }
     }
```